# how do I create a constant variable that can be modified constantly

Tags: python

If i'm not very clear let my explain I have this code -

```
health = {
    'Health': 10,
    'Enemy Health': 3
    }
import random
variable = random.choice([1 , 2 , 1])   
print "Attack/Flee"

turn1 = True
turn2 = False

while turn1:
    A = raw_input()
if A == "Attack" or "attack":
print health['Enemy Health'] - variable
```

what i'm trying to achieve is a turn based attack system, when the player attacks the variable actually changes. like this

```
Attack/Flee
1
Attack/flee
0
Attack/flee
-2
```

I'm trying to make this turn based as well so the enemy can also attack

Comment: `health['Enemy Health'] =health['Enemy Health'] - variable`  you just set the variable ... Im not sure what your stuck on ...

Comment: A *constant* is something that does not change. I guess you wanted to say something else? Anyway, to change value of `health['Enemy Health']`, you do: `health['Enemy Health'] = new_value`

Comment: Why do you want `variable` to be a variable? Why not a function?

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but `if A == "Attack" or "attack":` doesn't do what you think. See [Why does `a == b or c or d` always evaluate to True? \[duplicate\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20002503/953482) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not changing the variable enemy health

if you do

```
while turn1:
    print constant - random
```

your constant will remain the same, what you have to do if you dont want to change the constant, is creating another variable like this

```
enemy_life = health['Enemy Health']
    while turn1:
        A = raw_input()
        if A == "Attack" or "attack":
        enemy_life = enemy_life - variable
        print enemy_life
```

and if you want your wile to end after the "enemy_life" reaches 0 then:

```
    enemy_life = health['Enemy Health']
    while (enemy_life>0):
        A = raw_input()
        if A == "Attack" or "attack":
        enemy_life = enemy_life - variable
        print enemy_life
```